# DocumentDB: Possible to nest queries?

Tags: sql, subquery, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I want to check the partner.ids which are in a 30km radius of the user's position, and with these information I want to check which products these partners offer.

Can I nest queries with DocumentDB like the following way:

```
SELECT TOP 50 * FROM products doc WHERE doc._flags.published = true 
AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(doc.partner.pk, 
    SELECT VALUE doc.partner.pk FROM promo doc 
    JOIN shop IN doc.shops WHERE doc._flags.published = true AND doc._flags.deleted = false 
    AND ST_DISTANCE(shop._location, {"type": "Point", "coordinates":[52.520007, 13.404954]}) < 30000)
```

Or do I have to make two separated queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentDB does not support nested queries. You have to do them one at a time from the lowest level to the highest level. Note, from a performance perspective, that's essentially what a traditional SQL database does so you could be almost as fast... although it's a bit more work with DocumentDB.